# nice() library call or sys call?

Tags: c, linux, unix, operating-system, system-calls

Should a function to change the priority of the calling process (eg: nice()) be implemented as a library call or as a system call? I was reading about it online and from what I understood, it used to be a system call but it's a library call now. Why so?

Comment: It tends to depend on how who has defined the terms.  When you call a C function that wraps a system call, is it a system call or a function?  It depends on who you are.  For `nice()`, does the function make the `nice()` system call, or does it use a different, more general system call that can provide the same functionality?   Also consider `signal()` and `sigaction()` — the former is now usually a function that invoked the latter system call. It was not always thus.

Answer (score 1):

All functions are library calls. The question you're looking at is a sloppy shorthand for the question of whether or not there's a syscall that corresponds directly to the semantics, so that the library function can do something trivial along the lines of `return syscall(SYS_foo, ...);`.

Often it happens that at some point in history there was a syscall that corresponded fully to the function's operations at that point in history, but either:

- new requirements on the function rendered the existing syscall incapable of meeting the function's needs, or
- a bug was discovered in the syscall that's fundamental to its interface

In either case, if there's a reasonable way to implement the operation entirely with other syscalls, that usually makes more sense than implementing a "v2" of the syscall. Moreover, even if a new syscall is added, it's often added with further generality than the old interface needed, for extensibility or to be useful for satisfying other existing needs. Therefore it might not correspond directly to the function being implemented, just provide a means to obtain the functionality.